# Increasing the loop speed

Tags: python, performance, loops

I have 1 million loops to make. Is there anyway of processing this (and python loops in general) faster?

```
import numpy
#in a population of 1000 individuals of the same species, one individual has an advantageous mutation
#before, the average quantity of newborns per each 2 individuals per generation was 2 (no average change in pop)

popN, popM= 999, 1
period= 1000

reproductionDistN=[0.1, 0.2, 0.41, 0.19, 0.1] #expected value= 1.95
reproductionDistM=[0.1, 0.2, 0.39, 0.21, 0.1] #expected value= 2.05

def reproduce(pop, reproductionDist):
    newborns=numpy.random.choice(numpy.arange(0,5), p=reproductionDist) #numpy.arange(0,5)=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
    pop+=newborns
    return pop

for t in range(period):
    for n in range(popN): popN=reproduce(popN, reproductionDistN)  
    for m in range(popM): popM=reproduce(popM, reproductionDistM) 

print("Population of N:",popN)
print("Population of M:",popM)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways in general to make a loop faster:

1. Make the thing you're doing inside the loop faster, so that the computer is doing less work to achieve the same result.  This only works if you're able to find inefficiencies in your code and fix them.
2. Run more than one loop at the same time (i.e. instead of 1 thread doing 1M things, have 4 threads doing 250k things each).  This only works if you have multiple processors that can do the work in parallel *and* the work you're doing doesn't requires exclusive use of a shared resource (e.g. a disk) for its duration.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing python loops with numpy array operations often helps to improve performance.

In your example, you effectively do

```
pop = 100  # for example

for i in range(pop):
    pop += np.random.choice(5, p=reproductionDistM)
```

at each iteration.

All sampling and summing can be done in numpy without a loop:

```
pop = 100
pop += np.random.choice(5, p=reproductionDistM, size=pop).sum()
```

On my machine, this provides a large speedup (how much depends on value of `pop`, around 100 for the example).

On the other hand, this can waste a lot of RAM if the arrays are large. In this case, I often find it practical to balance speed and RAM by using numpy in batches.